# Power BI - Filter to count Number for Max Count

Tags: powerbi

I have the issue I can not go about. I want to use Card to count Number but only for max value of Count. So in my example it will be 5 not 9.

```
Number  Count
1       100
2       101
3       102
3       103
3       104
3       105
4       106
5       107
5       108
```

Comment: Do you want to have M or DAX solution for that?

Comment: What do you mean by `count Number for max value of Count`. Do you want count distinct Number? Why 5? Because there are 5 distinct values in column Number? Or maybe you select MAX(Count) = 108 (one row) and you then you check in Number column what is value for that - here it is also 5.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Remin - either way please

Comment: Ok, I understand that your `either way` means either M or DAX. Please explain the logic you want to get your desired results. See my second comment. Why have you chosen `5 not 9`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several steps.

1. Calculate the maximum `Count`
2. Find which `Number` values correspond to this max `Count`
3. Count the occurrences of these `Number` values

Here's one example of a measure that does this:

```
Count of Max = 
    VAR MaxCount = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Count]), ALLSELECTED(Table1))
    VAR MaxNumbers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[Number]), Table1[Count] = MaxCount)
    RETURN CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Number]), Table1[Number] IN MaxNumbers)
```

The last line can be written in many different other ways. For example,

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Number] IN MaxNumbers))
```

or

```
SUMX(Table1, 1*(Table1[Number] IN MaxNumbers))
```

---

**Edit:** From your comment, it looks like you don't want to do the third step mentioned above. In this case, you only have two steps.

```
Number for Max Count = 
    VAR MaxCount = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Count]), ALLSELECTED(Table1))
    RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Number]), Table1[Count] = MaxCount)
```

If there are multiple `Number` values associated with the maximal `Count` value, then this returns the max of those associated values.

Comment: @ Alexis Olson. It gives me zeros for all numbers except 5 (where it gave 1 or 2 depending on the code). What I am after is the following: Number / Desired Count: 1 / 100; 2/101; 3/105; 4/106; 5/108

Comment: Oh, it looks like you don't actually want to do the third step. I read your title as the count of the max number, not just that number. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible ways to do it in M. Paste this code in advanced editor.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Tca5DQAwCASwXa6m4E2yC2L/NSJdhSt3wyAwVYw0nDc+eF+P9VwvPvnDF3/XH2Y+", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Number = _t, Count = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Count", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "IsMax", each [Count] = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Count])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([IsMax] = true))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Here crucial is the third step where you add custom column `IsMax` which checks if it is max of `Count` column:

[image]

Alternative for selecting MAX value per category, you may find here:
[Select row with MAX value per category Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437962/select-row-with-max-value-per-category-power-bi)

And here is even more generalized approach with adding index per category:
[Index by category in Power BI equivalent to SQL row_number over partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438508/index-by-category-in-power-bi-equivalent-to-sql-row-number-over-partition)

Update. If you want max value per category - this is solution:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Tca5DQAwCASwXa6m4E2yC2L/NSJdhSt3wyAwVYw0nDc+eF+P9VwvPvnDF3/XH2Y+", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Number = _t, Count = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Count", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Number"}, {{"Grouped_by_Number", each List.Max([Count]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks, it just gives TRUE for the Max Number and Count (ie. 5 and 108. It does not work for Number 3.

Comment: So your `Count` column is a Category column. And you want to select max value of Count for each category? Is that right?

Comment: See update of my answer. If that is not it, please paste in your question full desired results, including no.5  no. 3 and other numbers. It stems out from your question that only 5 is the number you want to get.