# Selecting Distinct Values from sorted Table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have data query in my excel workbook to load data from a CSV-file. I want to use the Power Query-Editor to transform the data before working with them actually.

The simplified structure of the CSV-file are as shown in the html-table snippet below:

```html
<table style="text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:100px">Response-ID</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Task-ID</th>
    <th style="width:200px">Executed Action</th>
    <th style="width:200px">Status</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Date</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Some Task to be done</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>20.01.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Another Action done today</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>25.01.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>New Task</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>25.01.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>More actions in this matter</td>
    <td><b>Done</b></td>
    <td>26.01.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Another Task</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>27.02.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Whatever</td>
    <td><b>Done</b></td>
    <td>29.02.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>Now what?</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>02.03.2020</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Almost done...</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>02.03.2020</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is a Power Query M code to display only the latest entry from each unfinished Task-ID.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let
    Source = ResponseData //a copy of my actual data query "ResponseData" to work with in this case
    #"Transformed Table" = Table.Distinct(Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(Source, {{"Date", Order.Descending}})), "Task-ID"),
    #"Remove Finished Tasks" = Table.SelectRows(#"Transformed Table", each ([Status] <> "Done" and [Status] <> "Canceled"))
in
    #"Remove Finished Tasks"
```

This code actually returns a list of all open tasks. But against my expectation it only contains the oldest response-ID of each task instead of the newest one. Changing the sort-order in the `#"Transformed Table"`-line returns the very same result in a reversed order. So basically sorting the table has no influence on the resulting data at all...

EDITED the code above according to the answer by Ron Rosenfeld -> Buffering the sorted table does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I don't fully understand (seems to have something to do with query folding), `Power Query Remove Duplicates` when run on a certain data sources, apparently does not respect the sorting order.  But if you use `Table.Buffer`, then it ensures that folding will not take place and that the `Remove Duplicates` will take place after the sorting/filtering.

Not sure which would be faster on large datasets, though -- `Table.Buffer` versus `Table.Group`

**CSV File**

```
Response-ID,Task-ID,Executed Action,Status,Date
1,A,Some Task to be done,Open,20.01.2020
2,A,Another Action done today,Open,25.01.2020
3,B,New Task,Open,25.01.2020
4,A,More actions in this matter,Done,26.01.2020
5,C,Another Task,Open,27.02.2020
6,B,Whatever,Done,29.02.2020
7,D,Now what?,Open,02.03.2020
8,C,Almost done...,Open,02.03.2020
```

First few lines of **MCode** is a bit different, but this should give you the gist:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Response-ID", Int64.Type}, {"Task-ID", type text}, {"Executed Action", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Date", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type date}}, "en-150"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type with Locale", each ([Status] = "Open")),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Buffered Table" = Table.Buffer(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Buffered Table", {"Task-ID"}),
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Task-ID", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows1"
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's it! Never had I expected such a flaw in this feature... Buffering the sorted table does the trick.

Comment: Just out of curiosity as a beginner to Power Query M: How would the solution look like with grouping? I didn't think of grouping as a feature to just store data. Would it be faster? Over time there will be many entries (probabably way over 10.000) in my table.

Comment: @GuidoT To use grouping and also retain the column data that does not participate in the grouping gets pretty complex. I suggest you stick with the `Table.Buffer` method unless you find it quite slow on large data, at which time post a new question.  If you don't need the non-participatory columns, then merely select the `Task-Id` column and group by on that, with **Max** as the operation on the `Date` column.

Comment: @GuidoT One way of retaining the non-participatory columns is by duplicating the query, doing your filter/group on one, and then joining the appropriate rows.  And I don't know which way would be faster.  But if it comes to that, you can test both methods.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook