# Removing duplicates in Powerquery is ignoring that I've sorted the data (so removes wrong duplicate)

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have this (example) data in Excel in a table named `Table1`:

```
| PC Item  | Priority |
|----------|----------|
| AN123169 | P3       |
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P3       |
```

After sorting into *Priority* order and removing duplicates based on PC Item I would expect a *P1* record to remain.  Instead I'm getting *P3*.

The [help file](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/remove-duplicates-power-query-d9cffc69-dc5d-4d94-8b66-72779688874d) states:

> Removes all rows from a Power Query table, in the Query Editor, where
>   the values in the selected columns duplicate earlier values.

My understanding of this is it keeps the first record and removes subsequent records?

The `M` code I'm using is:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PC Item", type text}, {"Priority", type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"PC Item", Order.Ascending}, {"Priority", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows", {"PC Item"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

After `#"Sorted Rows"` I have this table, which is sorted correctly:

```
| PC Item  | Priority |
|----------|----------|
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P1       |
| AN123169 | P3       |
| AN123169 | P3       |
```

After `#"Removed Duplicates"` I have:

```
| PC Item  | Priority |
|----------|----------|
| AN123169 | P3       |
```

Surely I should have a P1 record?

---

My first thought was to reverse the sort, but with this original data I get `P3` returned as the unique value:

```
| PC Item | Priority |
|---------|----------|
| AN310C4 | P3       |
| AN310C4 | P1       |
| AN310C4 | P1       |
```

and with this original data I get `P1` returned:

```
| PC Item | Priority |
|---------|----------|
| AN310C4 | P1       |
| AN310C4 | P1       |
| AN310C4 | P3       |
```

### The question:

So I guess my question is - how does sort work seeing as the subsequent `M` code appears to ignore the fact that I've sorted the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Table.Buffer` to cache intermediate query results and avoid query folding when deleting duplicates.

---

**Sample data:**

[image]

---

**Updated `M`:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PC Item", type text}, {"Priority", type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"PC Item", Order.Ascending}, {"Priority", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Buffer Table" = Table.Buffer(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Buffer Table", {"PC Item"})
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

Documentation (very little) found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-buffer). Informative video found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqDdnNxSgHQ).

I found other ways to "break" query folding using remove error lines in the table or adding an index-column (and removing it). However, a buffer seems neat to me.

Comment: I had to look up [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-folding) which was pretty close to what I imagined it to be.  Buffering seems to do the trick.  Thanks!