# Is there a way to filter the "top N" values by a category in power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the following data:

[image: Exemple of table]

I'm trying to filter this table in a way that I can get the 35 max values by "Category A".

The goal is to have an end table with all the values between the max value and the 35th greater value, by item in "Category A",but coudn't figure a way to do this.

I tried using:

`= Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step", each [Values] >= List.Max(#"Previous Step"[Values])-35)`

But since each entry in "Category A" has a different max value, it's not exactly what I'm needing.

Does anybody knows if there's a way to do this in Power Query?

By the way, I'm doing this on power query because I'll need to do some calculations and I find it easier to do so inside power query. I don't know if in Power BI there's a easier way to do this, but I don't know much of DAX.

Anyway, thank you in advance!

Comment: The answers to this question might be a good clue to solve your problem. Instead of top 1 get the top N. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51437962/1903793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX would be your best option using [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax). However, in Power Query, depending on volumes of Data, you could sort the table by Value, then add an index column 1...n and then filter for the index column <= 35.

Comment: I coudn't get RANKX to work the way I needed, but thanks for the help. In the end, I manually selected the top 35 for each category.